# Trouble with installing the package telescope-posts

Tags: bash, meteor, telescope

I am trying to get rid of the character/text limit which is found in the package https://github.com/TelescopeJS/Telescope/tree/master/packages/telescope-posts.

I tried just doing "meteor add telescope-posts" but I received the error:

```
=> Errors while parsing arguments:           

While adding package telescope-posts:
error: no such package
```

I then tried to create a package but when I enter ".meteor/packages" or "myProjectName/.meteor/packages" I receive:

```
-bash: .meteor/packages: Permission denied
```

Any help on how to install the package telescope-posts is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

`meteor add telescope:posts`

More likely, you should look at: https://telescope.readme.io/v0.20/docs/installing-telescope

Comment: Thank you! I kept putting a "-" instead of a ":"